# T-SQL - Using GUID's Across tables for storing common information?

Tags: sql-server, database-schema

I started building a database to manage things like vehicles, finances, bills, work history, residence history....etc.

I'm mostly doing this as a learning exercise to teach myself different methods of schema design and ground up development. I've been a database developer for 4 years, but I've only ever worked on the same system/schema. Even my ground up development of new features still have to abide by the existing Schema.

Anyways, I have tables for things like Vehicle Registration, Vehicle Loans/Purchases, Bills, etc. But rather than storing their billing info (payment amount, occurrence, etc), I thought maybe I could put a GUID column on every table, and then store the billing info by the GUID, and then have some sort of view or function that lets me look up the object_id (table) for a particular GUID.

1. Is this design method a good way to do things?
2. How would I go about designing the function/view to return the objectid / tablename for specific GUID's?

EDIT: I guess this is a poor explanation, so here's a quick example:

Table: **VehicleRegistration**

This table would have information like license plate, when the registration is good for, etc.

Table: **VehicleLoan**

This table would have loan information about each vehicle (amount financed, term, apr, date of purchase, etc).

Both of those tables would also have information like Billing Date, Occurence, Estimated Amount, etc. But instead of storing that data in the two tables, I would store it in another table called BillingInfo or something like that. Obviously I could add a FK on the two tables that point to the PK on the BillingInfo table. But that would mean every table that requires billing information would require that FK on it. Rather than creating that FK on every table...what if instead, every row in VehicleRegistration and VehicleLoan had a unique ID. And I would store the billing info by unique ID instead.

And since it's unque across tables, I would have a function or view to tell me which table that GUID is in. (keep in mind, this is a very small personal database, so for now, speed and optimization is not a concern).

If I applied this method to all common info, like billing information, then I could avoid having to put a FK on every table that needs it. I could just create the table and use the Unique ID's instead?

Comment: What is the reason for a GUID over a vanilla auto-incrementing Identity column?

Comment: @AlexK. It would allow me to look up any row in any table with just one ID.

The other way around this would be to have a column on every table that has billing information and to put a FK pointing to the PK of the Billing Info table? But then if I have other tables I'd like to create for common info in the future, I would have to add a new column to every one of those tables again.

I also have auto-increment PK's on each table as well. The GUID's would just be used for global lookup.

Comment: Can you provide a small working example of what you are thinking of, either just the table structure, with column names and constraints, an ER diagram, or just the create table SQL, but at present I for one am pretty lost at what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Sorry folks, I guess I'm not so good at explaining this. haha. See my edited posted and see if that helps?

Comment: Wouldn't that mean that if you had 6 records in `VehicleRegistration`, and 4 records in `VehicleLoan`, you would then have 10 unique ID's accross the two tables, and so would need to have 10 records in `BillingInfo` anyway?  I am struggling to see any benefit whatsoever to this approach over just having the columns in the original table, but it would increase memory used, decrease performance and remove referential integrity.

Comment: Or if Billing Information truly is a common asset between tables, then add the foreign key accordingly, although adding the column might be more work, it is a better approach.

Comment: I'm not saying it's beneficial, that's the whole reason I'm posting this, to ask about it. Here's another example...since the previous examples were all one to one relationships. What if I had a one to many relationship? Where I store logging information for each of the tables? So one row in [VehicleRegistration] could have multiple rows in some log table, maybe a billing history, and [VehicleLoan] as well. Using the GUID I could store it's billing history for each GUID even though each GUID could tie to a different table.

Comment: Granted, I could create a BillingInfo table and a BillingInfoHistory table. But again, this is why I'm asking. I'm aware of the ways this "should" be done...I'm just trying to explore other ways of doing things.

Comment: If it's a dumb idea then it's a dumb idea, I was just curious if this was a technique that could be used in any way. I guess this is more of a nosql thing maybe? (I have zero experience with non-relational databases). I work with SalesForce a lot and I know they have something similar to that...every object has it's own unique ID...users, accounts, assets, etc. You can put any uniqueID into the URL and it will load that objects page. But I don't think they are using SQL.

Comment: hey @chadwin, i guess the less complicated your database is the better.  you can have a look at this link........... https://www.google.co.nz/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjSvumm79TSAhVFtJQKHX4VAZkQFggYMAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fstackoverflow.com%2Fquestions%2F371762%2Fwhat-exactly-is-guid-why-and-where-i-should-use-it&usg=AFQjCNFyYgd7AY46zWqaVGVyJXcG07j7Jg&sig2=77mYpMGDRwZs19JtDoknBQ&bvm=bv.149397726,d.dGo